# group weighted average excluding max values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with columns for data_value, weight, and category.

I know how to calculate a weighted average of data_value for every category using SUM and GROUP BY.

However, I also need to calculate weighted averages excluding the two maximum values from each category.

**Edit**

So for example, I might have a table like this:

```
| ID | Group | value | weight|  
|--- |------ |------ |-------|  
| 1  |  A    |  2.0  |  1    |
| 2  |  A    |  1.5  | 2     |
| 3  |  A    |  50.0 | 1     |
| 4  |  A    |   1   |  3    |
| 5  |  A    |  100  |  2    |
| 6  |  B    |   25  |  1    |
| 7  |  B    |   2   |  2    |
| 8  |  B    |   1   |  1    |
| 9  |  B    |   10  |  1    |
```

The averages would be:

```
(2*1+1.5*2+1*3)/(1+2+3)
```

for group A, and

```
(2*2+1*1)/(2+1)
```

for group B.

**End Edit**

Can anyone help me out with this?

I'm relatively new to SQL and can't quite figure it out.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Exclude this two maximal values then calculate average.

Comment: @Akina, the problem is that I need to exclude the weights of the maximum values as well as the values themselves, and I can't figure out how to formulate a query to do that.

Comment: What is your version of MySql? Also, what if there are more than 2 rows for a group with the same max value?

Comment: @forpas, I'm running 10.3.28-MariaDB.  And I think it would be incredibly rare for my dataset to have duplicate max values, but it it happens, I'd be fine with dropping just the first one it finds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function (or `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` if there is a case of duplicate values in the column `value`) to filter out the top 2 values of each group and then aggregate to get the weighted average:

```
SELECT `Group`, SUM(value * weight) / SUM(weight) avg_value
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `Group` ORDER BY value DESC) rn
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE rn > 2
GROUP BY `Group`
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f908a8706535d778534c19d8feee5fcf).

Comment: That works, thank you! (Except the avg should be SUM(value*weight)/SUM(weight).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT (SUM - SELECT MAX(data_value) - SELECT MAX(NOT IN MAX(data_value)) )

GROUP BY

Comment: That would work fine if I was doing a straight average, but for a weighted average I need to exclude not only the data values but also their corresponding weights.